# Sending a unique link to a users email

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to invite a user to login to my backend system. When the form is submitted with the user's last name, first name, middle initial, email, and Message (optional) it should send a unique link to the user's email to let them know they were invited. When the link is clicked it will bring them to a page where they can create a username and password to the account (don't need help with this part).

VIEW FILE:

```
    {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Invite Teacher</h1> 
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ form_errors(newTeacherForm) }}
            <form id="new_teacher_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ path('t60_cms_super_usermanagement_inviteteacher', {'account_id': account_id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(newTeacherForm) }}>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ form_widget(newTeacherForm.lastname, {'id': 'inputTitle', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}}) }} 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    {{ form_widget(newTeacherForm.firstname, {'id': 'inputTitle', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}}) }}
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    {{ form_widget(newTeacherForm.middleinitial, {'id': 'inputTitle', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'MI'}}) }}
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    {{ form_widget(newTeacherForm.email, {'id': 'inputTitle', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}}) }} 
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    {{ form_widget(newTeacherForm.lastname, {'id': 'inputTitle', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Message (Optional)'}}) }} 
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form_rest(newTeacherForm) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Invite Teacher</button>
    </div>
</form>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

ROUTE:

```
t60_cms_super_usermanagement_inviteteacher:
    pattern: /cms/usermanagement/invteacher/{account_id}
    defaults: { _controller:Think60SiteBundle:SuperAdmin:inviteTeacher }
```

Controller:

```
public function inviteTeacherAction($account_id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repos = $em->getRepository('Think60SiteBundle:Account');
        $query = $repos->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.id = :account_id')
            ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id)
            ->getQuery();
        $account = $query->getSingleResult();

        $newTeacherForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('lastname', 'text')
            ->add('firstname', 'text')
            ->add('middleinitial', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->getForm();
        if($newTeacherForm->isValid()){
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Your Invited To Join Think60')
                ->setFrom('send@example.com')
                ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'Think60SiteBundle:SuperAdmin:email.txt.twig',
                        array('name' => $name)
                    ));
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        }   
    return $this->render('Think60SiteBundle:SuperAdmin:inviteteacher.html.twig', array(
            'newTeacherForm' => $newTeacherForm->createView(),
            'account_id' => $account_id,
        ));
    }
```

I know the controller is probably wrong in multiple spots just because I'm not 100% how this is going to work. So it's in an unstable state. But thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Which is exactly the question, please?

Comment: How do I send a unique link to the user via email once an admin in the system invites them?

Comment: http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php should work, but I'm afraid this is not the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. But I think the easiest would be to create an "Invitation" entity that contains a unique, not guessable id, and the email adress of the invited user.

The invite link contains the invitation id as part of the url (e.g. /join/37d2e90ab3). If a user calls this url, put the id into his session.

Registration is only possible, when the session contains a valid invitation id. When the registration is successful, remove the id from the session and delete the invitation entity (or mark it as used).